# Asynchronously populate gridview on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous

I would like to populate a Gridview which is inside an update panel on button click. Currently the gridview is getting populated however doesn't show up on screen. What am I missing?
Below is the code that I'm using:

```
  public delegate void BindGrid_Delegate();
  protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        try
        {
            // databind of all the controls
            BindGrid_Delegate bd = new  BindGrid_Delegate(BindGrid);
            IAsyncResult ar = bd.BeginInvoke(null, null); //invoking the method
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "PageException", "alert('" + ex.Message + "');", true);
        }
  }

  private void BindGrid()
  {
      try
      {
          DataSet ResultDataSet = GetData();
          gvShowResult.DataSource = ResultDataSet; 
          gvShowResult.DataBind();
          UpdatePanel2.Update();
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "PageException", "alert('" + ex.Message + "');", true);
      }
  }
```

Updatemode for updatepanel is conditional. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Why don't you call directly BindGrid() inside the btnSearch_Click? You should remove delegate and IAsyncResult because it will not help you run better.

Comment: Hey Tim, yes if I call BidnGrid directly it works like a charm. However I'd like to use Asynchronous call as I'm trying to learn it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that you call `DataBind()` and `Update()` on the non-UI thread. UI controls should only be modified on the thread that creates them.

You can still call your `GetData()` method in a seperate thread, e.g. using [Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx).

In your `btnSearch_Click` method:

```
Task.Factory
    .StartNew(() => GetData())
    .ContinueWith(t => 
    {
        gvShowResult.DataSource = t.Result; 
        gvShowResult.DataBind();
        UpdatePanel2.Update();
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

This calls `GetData()` on a seperate thread and executes the continuation on the UI thread.

Comment: hey Dirk, which namespace Task belong to. I'm only getting Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Task as the available namespace.

Comment: @GargiNarain Documentation for the [Task class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) and the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx)

Comment: @Dirk, the question is about ASP .Net and there is no such thing as UI threads in there. You probably created your answer thinking of Windows applications.

Comment: @FlorinDumitrescu Yes, I realized that after I read your answer. I missed the ASP.Net tag and the question/code looked like windows forms.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are multiple problems with your code. First of all you are not letting ASP .Net know that you want to execute the asynchronous method as part of the request. In your code the request returns after the call to bd.BeginInvoke(), when instead it should return after the async call to BindGrid is completed.

The second problem is that while you are asynchronously calling the BindGrid() method, there is no asynchronous I/O in your code, so you are not freeing any of the ASP .Net threads while the data is retrieved. You are just delaying the call to BindGrid(). [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163725.aspx) article should help you related to the above problems.

If using the .Net 4.5 is an option, you should try creating the asynchronous behavior using the async and await pair. Check [this article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4) that explains how to do that in ASP .Net MVC.

Comment: Thanks Florin, let me explore the articles and I shall get back to you.